# A melt call that resembles a transpose

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I'm wondering whether my two step solution can be reduced to one `melt()` call or done more simply somehow using `data.table`.

My data:

```
DT <- data.table(category = c("x", "y"), `2010` = c(10, 20), `2011` = c(40, 43))
DT # Has much more columns in reality
   category 2010 2011
1:        x   10   40
2:        y   20   43
```

Expected output:

```
   year  x  y
1: 2010 10 20
2: 2011 40 43
```

Current solution:

```
library(data.table)

melt(DT, id.vars = "category", variable.name = "year")[, dcast(.SD, year ~ category)]
```

Comment: 'almost' solution: `as.data.table( t(DT), keep.rownames = TRUE )[2:.N,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` version >= 1.12.4, you can use `transpose` as follows for this particular case:

```
transpose(DT, keep.names="year", make.names="category")
```

output:

```
   year  x  y
1: 2010 10 20
2: 2011 40 43
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `recast` (wrapper for `melt/dcast`)

```
library(reshape2)
recast(DT, variable ~ category, id.var = 'category')
```